# I keep getting "IndexOutOfRangeException" on my Unity project. UNITY + PHP

Tags: php, unity-game-engine, authentication

(I was trying to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVdjlXgbiMM&t=6s)

I'm trying to implement a login feature in a Unity project, I've successfully done the register part and it works, but I can't get the login part to work.

Every time I try to get info from the database, it gives me the "IndexOutOfRangeException" on C#.
I think that the problem is in the PHP part tho, since the C# seems to be fine.

C# Code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class login : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField namefield, passwordfield;
    public Button submitButton;
    public GameObject popUp;
    public Text text;

    public void CallLogin()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Login2());
    }

    IEnumerator Login()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("name", namefield.text);
        form.AddField("password", passwordfield.text);
        WWW www = new WWW("http://localhost/sqlconnect/login2.php", form);
        yield return www;

        Debug.Log(www.text);

        if (www.text[0] == '0')
        {
            bddManeger.username = namefield.text;
            bddManeger.tempo = int.Parse(www.text.Split('\t')[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("User Login Failed. Error #" + www.text);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Login2()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("name", namefield.text);
        form.AddField("password", passwordfield.text);
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost/sqlconnect/login2.php", form);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();


        Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);


        if (www.downloadHandler.text[0] == '0')
        {
            bddManeger.username = namefield.text;
            bddManeger.tempo = int.Parse(www.downloadHandler.text.Split('\t')[1]);
            UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("User Error: " + www.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        VerifyInputs();
    }

    public void VerifyInputs()
    {
        submitButton.interactable = (namefield.text.Length >= 8 && passwordfield.text.Length >= 8);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
        {
            if (namefield.GetComponent<InputField>().isFocused)
            {
                passwordfield.GetComponent<InputField>().Select();
            }
            if (passwordfield.GetComponent<InputField>().isFocused)
            {
                namefield.GetComponent<InputField>().Select();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PHP

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'apolobdd');

    //check connection
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "1: falha na conecção";
        exit();
    }

    $username = $_POST["name"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    //check name
    $namecheckquery ="SELECT username, salt, hash, tempo FROM users WHERE username = '" . $usename . "';";
    $namecheck = mysqli_query($con, $namecheckquery) or die ("2: Verificação Falhou");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($namecheck) != 0)
    {
        echo "5: either no user with name or more than one";
        exit();
    }

    //get login info from query
    $existinginfo = mysqli_fetch_assot($namecheck);
    $salt = $existinginfo["salt"];
    $hash = $existinginfo["salt"];

    $loginhash = crypt($password, $salt);
    if ($hash != $loginhash)
    {
        echo "6: Incorrect Password";
        exit();
    }

    echo "0\t" . $existinginfo["tempo"];
?>
```

Comment: which line gives exception?

Comment: on C# the error is on line 53, im currently using the Coroutine Login2 (i was trying to do it with UnityWebRequest instead of WWW), but i still think it's on the PHP part, and i suspect it's between lines 16 and 22

Comment: either www.text or www.downloadhandler.text are empty arrays and you are trying to get the first element

Comment: i mean, i know they are empty, that's why i suspect the problem beeing in the PHP part. I just don't know why they are coming back empty.

Comment: So, I "fixed" the IndexOutOfRangeException, i wrote "$usename" instead of "$username" on the PHP file. But now the it's giving me the error "5: either no user with name or more than one".

Comment: You know that your current PHP is also **wide open for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**? You should rather use a [prepared statement](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is UnityWebRequest.text is a string and you are treating it like an array. Code some script to parse the string as needed.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandler-text.html

```
  if (www.downloadHandler.text[0] == '0')
```

and possibly there may be an issue here as www is deprecated

```
  if (www.text[0] == '0')
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html

Try WWWForm instead

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html

Comment: yup this helped a lot, i was just beeing a tard and was writting code I didn't fully understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just here to update.

I didn't fully understand the code and what it did, and there were some mistakes on my part of the code.

But thanks to the people who tried to help anyways.